# DTS.runtime.Application Error With Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, .net-assembly, sql-server-data-tools, vssdk

> Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise v16.11.15 SS Integration services 3.16
> I try to Load my DTSX Package as File with Framework C# class.  I add
> reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime to my project with browse
> dll within : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\150 When
> running reach the instruction :
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application a = new
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application(); I get the following
> output Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file
> or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=15.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
> dependencies. The specified file can not be found.'

the same Script.Main is working perfect when i downgrade the DTS.Runtime reference to the ManagedDTS version 14 or older. The problem that the TargetServerVersion of SQL Server 2019 is only able in Version 15.

If someone has a solution i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find solution to workaround this bug ; i have changed the visual studio project Template from Console App (.Net Framework ) to SSIS Project and then i put my code on Task Script Component. Naturally i add reference to new ManagedDTS  dll for VS 2019 to my project .
Now solution is running well and i can call the function
App.SaveAndUpdateVersionToXml sucessfully to upgrade automatically all packages DTSX by Framework .Net Script.
I share with you this blog which very supported me to make solution.
https://blog.bartekr.net/2018/02/28/upgrading-ssis-projects-part-iii/
Thank you for you all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).